# Rellenar con espacios un campo de DB2 en SQL

Tags: db2

Tengo un trozo de una consulta SQL en la que recupero de un campo, desde la posición 3, los tres últimos números. Debo pasarlo a character porque el campo es de 6.

Necesito añadirle a este trozo algo que le meta tres espacios en blanco por la izquierda, he probado con el ldap y no he sabido hacerlo o es que no funciona para esto:

```
CAST(SUBSTR(TMCTID,3,3) AS CHAR(6) ) SMAZON,
```

Answer (score 0):

Estaba investigando y encontré esto aunque es una respuesta de una versión antigua:

Supón que queremos hacer el *padding* por la derecha y que nos queden en total 25 caracteres, entonces creas una cadena de 25 espacios y le concatenas el *string* en cuestión y del resultado tomamos los 25 caracteres que estén a la derecha.

```
select

right(space(25) + c1, 25)

from
(

select cast('1' as varchar(25))

union all

select cast('11' as varchar(25))

union all

select cast('2' as varchar(25))

) as t1(c1)

go
```

Te dejo el enlace de la de donde lo obtuve: https://microsoft.public.es.sqlserver.narkive.com/dsh6SrR5/rellenar-campo-char-con-espacios-en-blanco

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar espacios a la izquierda, simplemente agregas ese string y lo concatenas, siguiendo tu ejemplo quedaría:

```
'   '||SUBSTR(TMCTID,3,3)
```

donde entre las comillas tienes 3 espacios.

Comment: muchas gracias Pablo. Me lo apunto